# Multi-task learning with data augmentation

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, multitasking

I am wondering how to train the neural model when I have two separate tasks with an **unequal amount of data** for each task. For example, consider the case below:

> **Task-1.** A classification problem on one dataset that has entries with two labels (0, 1). The amount of training instances: 20,000
>
> **Task-2.** A classification problem on one dataset that has entries with three labels (0, 1, 2). The amount of training instances: 1.6M

I am trying to develop a network where a shared network first tries to encode each instance (of each task) and then project the encoded instances through 2 output layers for solving each task separately. Specifically, the shared network is BERT encoder (that I don't need to train). So all I have to do is training two output (linear) layers for each task, and optimizing them through multi-task loss function. But I have trouble perceiving how to do this when there are unequal number of instances for each task. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a loss function that ignores loss when label of one kind is not available for an instance.

```
loss = i1 * loss1(pred1, label1) + i2 * loss2(pred2, label2)
```

Where `loss1` and `loss2` can be cross entropy loss for predicting task1 and task2 respectively. `i1` and `i2` are indicator variables that are `1` if label for that task is available and `0` otherwise. You may also need to add different weight to the losses for better result.